# Error in uploading file to 000webhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting

I'm new to php and this is my first time trying to hosting an website. I'm using codeigniter as my framework. I would like to hosting my website however it give me this kind of error.  It is because my index.php and .htaccess file is wrong? If yes, can I get the right one ? My question may be duplicate from before, and i'm asking it because i could not understand the solution or could'n find an appropriate solution. Thanks in advance [image: ![This is the error that i get]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci2FH.png)

Comment: It looks like you are missing the password for your database connection in /application/config/database.php - check that your credentials are correct.

Comment: thank you sir! yes i have change the config in the database.php file. it should be according the name given at Manage Database on 000webhost Cpanel. Right now, i think my website can run however it doesn run the right page. i have an specific page for the home page, how can i set for 000webhost to run that specific page?